# "Hide page source" (Change page) based on noscript

Tags: php, html, jquery, encryption, right-click

I know this type of question have been made here before, but mine is diferent. Most people ask how to hide the page source code, which is impossible because the browser needs to render the page. My question is:
If an user has the browser's javascript disabled, is there anway to redirect him to a HTML page with something like "Looks like your browser is outdated by 25 years. Please enable javascript in your browser and try again. ", using php?
Note that the page source is not being hidden, but the person is actually being redirected somewhere else because a php script detected abnormal browser behavior.
I need this because I'm implementing an anti-adblock script.

Comment: Hello @PickleRiiiick instead redirecting user to new page you can use `<noscript>Looks like your browser is outdated by 25 years. Please enable javascript in your browser and try again.</noscript>`

Comment: If I do that, the current page source will still be available to the user.

Comment: Hello @PickleRiiiick is my answer is helpfull to you.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Yes, it worked, but please edit your answer and add this code below:

`/* Adding meta to header */
function add_meta_tags() {
echo '<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.0;url=https://google.com">
</noscript>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');`

This one is for wordpress.

Comment: Good to hear that it's working. (:

Comment: BTW, the current page source will still be available to the user in any case; just slightly more annoying to access.

Comment: Hello @PickleRiiiick if got an answer please accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.0;url=nojs/index/your_page_to_redirect">
</noscript>
```

This is for WordPress

```
/* Adding meta to header */ 
function add_meta_tags() 
{ echo '<noscript> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.0;url=https://google.com"> </noscript>'; 
} 
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags');
```